# How to use ng-repeat in directive with isolate scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to use ng-repeat in a directive that has an isolate scope, but I can't seem to get it working.

When I add an isolate scope to my directive, ng-repeat seems to not be able to see `items`, which I understand.

However, even if I use the `=` isolate scope, I get the error message:

`Error: Syntax Error: Token 'Object' is unexpected, expecting []] at column 9 of the expression [[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]] starting at [Object],[object Object],[object Object]].`

Here is a jsFiddle of ng-repeat working in a directive with no isolate scope:

http://jsfiddle.net/urlology/DA47k/3/

And using a `=` isolate scope:

http://jsfiddle.net/urlology/CL4AT/11/

As a code snippet:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.open = false;

  $scope.items = [{
      name: 'A',
      value: 1
    },
    {
      name: 'B',
      value: 2
    },
    {
      name: 'C',
      value: 3
    }
  ];
});

app.directive('myDirective', ['$compile', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var items = attrs.items;
      console.log('items %o', items);
      var itemLabelField = attrs.itemLabelField
      var template =
        '<ul>' +
        '<li data-ng-repeat="item in ' + items + '">' +
        '{{item.' + itemLabelField + '}}' +
        '</li>' +
        '</ul>';

      // Render the template.
      element.html('').append($compile(template)(scope));
    }
  }
}]);
```

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <div my-directive items="items" item-label-field="name"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's complaining about your template.

By doing `'<li data-ng-repeat="item in ' + scope.items + '">'` you are in fact converting scope.items to a string. You don't want that, you want it to go through the items in your items array.

So you would do: `'<li data-ng-repeat="item in items">'`

You've already added items to your scope through the scope property:

```
scope: {
    items: "=",
    itemLabelField: "@" //read below
}
```

That's enough to fix your problem, but as you can tell, I've also added itemLabelField so you don't need to use `var itemLabelField = attrs.itemLabelField`. The @ binder binds by value rather than the parent's scope.

So instead of `'{{item.' + itemLabelField + '}}'` you can do `'{{item[itemLabelField]}}'`.

Now you'll find your link function only has a plain string template with a compile. Ideally you'd use a template property instead of manually inserting code inside the element.

```
template:
    '<ul>' +
        '<li ng-repeat="item in items">' +
        '{{item[itemLabelField]}}' +
        '</li>' +
    '</ul>'
```

You could even put it in a seperate file and use the templateUrl property.

Here's the full changed code: http://jsfiddle.net/DA47k/12/

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.open = false;

    $scope.items = [
        { name: 'A', value: 1 },
        { name: 'B', value: 2 },
        { name: 'C', value: 3 }
    ];
});

app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            items: "=",
            itemLabelField: "@"
        },
        template:
            '<ul>' +
                '<li ng-repeat="item in items">' +
                    '{{item[itemLabelField]}}' +
                '</li>' +
            '</ul>'
    }
});
```

And just to add, for consistency use either one of ng-xxxx or data-ng-xxxx (or ng:xxxx) attributes rather than mixing them.

Comment: What is the point in passing in both the entire items array and itemLabelField? The itemLabelField values are in the items array. Seems redundant.

Comment: Just keeping it consistent with the question. It may have a different value in practice depending on where and how it's used. But yeah, in this example it's better to hard-code it so `item[itemLabelField]` becomes `item.name`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a working example using the isolated scope.

http://jsfiddle.net/DA47k/6/

You only need to pass in the object to the isolated scope with '=' and then you can access its properties in your template with dot notation instead of passing them in a new attribute.

```
app.directive('myDirective', ['$compile', function($compile) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        items: '='
    },    
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

        var template =
            '<ul>' +
                '<li data-ng-repeat="item in items">' +
                    '{{item.name}}' +
                '</li>' +
            '</ul>';

        // Render the template.
        element.html('').append($compile(template)(scope));
    }
}
}]);
```